# How to lock all the streams under integration stream in clearcase in UCM?

Tags: perl, scripting, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

How can I lock all the streams under integration stream in ClearCase UCM?

Comment: What does this have to do with Perl?

Comment: @Ether: because ClearCase comes with its own Perl installation: `ccperl`, making perl the scripting language of choice for that kind of task. My answer illustrates however that you don't need advanced scripting for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

The [`cleartool lock` operation in UCM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm) is not a recursive operation.
If you only lock the integration stream, it won't lock the substream

You need to list all the streams under an integration stream and lock them individually.

```
cleartool lsstream -s -in stream:My_Int_Stream@\myPVob -r
```

combined with gawk, you don't even need to script it:

```
cleartool lsstream -s -in stream:My_Int_Stream@\myPVob -r | gawk "{print \"cleartool lock -nc stream:\"$1\"@\\myPVob\"}"
```

Note the restrictions in the man page: you probably need to be the owner of those streams to be able to lock them.
Note also the `-r` to make sure you have all the sub-streams, and not the direct child streams of the Integration one.